# Conversion for Delphi 2009 unicode issue

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2009, delphi-7

I converting a lecacy app from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2009.
I got this error: **E2010 Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'AnsiChar'**
How can I fix it ? I tried to declare Alphabet: Ansistring[AlphabetLength] but that failed.

```
const
  AlphabetLength = 64;
  Alphabet: string[AlphabetLength] = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';

function TBase64.ValueToCharacter(value: Byte; var character: char): boolean;
begin
  Result := true;
  if (value > AlphabetLength-1) then
    Result := false
  else
// Compile error E2010 Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'AnsiChar'
    character := Alphabet[value+1];
end;    

function TBase64.CharacterToValue(character: char; var value: byte): boolean;
begin
  Result := true;
  value := Pos(character, Alphabet);
  if value = 0 then
    Result := false
  else
    value := value-1;
end;
```

Comment: the "string[...]" construct is called ShortString; it is Ansi only, and should be deprecated. Serg has the right answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid using the deprecated ShortString type in Unicode Delphi versions (2009 and later):

```
const
  AlphabetLength = 64;
  Alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
```

the above change should be enough.
You must also think about changing from 1-byte AnsiChars to 2-byte Chars.

edit (jeroen pluimers):

Here is [some documentation on the string types](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/stringtypes_xml.html).

Comment: ShortString is deprecated only in Delphi.NET as far as I know.

Comment: +1; I edited your answer to point to some string types documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use

```
Alphabet : String = 'ABCDEFGH...'?
```

Or if you are sure that you only use ANSI characters (which seems to be the case here), you can just cast:

```
character := Char (Alphabet [value+1]);
```

It seems that the short string type is using `AnsiChar` internally even in D2009 and higher.

Comment: ShortString not only seems to be it is definitely an "array of AnsiChar". ShortString is inherited from TurboPascal and the internal layout limits it to max. 255 characters.